# How do I export a private variable to a public variable in javaScript (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, I have a calculation program like this:

```
function cal(salary, additionalSalary) {
  var salary;
  var additionalSalary;
  var totalPay = salary + additionalSalary;
}

function 401k() {
  var specialAccount = totalPay * 0.37;
  var normalAccount = totalPay - specialAccount;
}
```

My question is how do I have the totalPay variable be exported out from the function to make it a public variable to be used in 401k function. Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that you add `return totalPay` to your `cal()` function and then whenever you want to know it's value, you call the `cal()` function with its two arguments and you get the return value.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. I believe you want to decouple these two functions. So, I would suggest calling the ```401k``` function with one argument ie ```totalPay```. I mean to use ```401k(totalPay) {```. It's not recommended to use global variables in a file in singleton instance pattern. As NodeJs uses singleton pattern, I would suggest the above approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return the `totalPay` ,like this, from the function `cal(salary, additionalSalary)` :

```
function cal(salary, additionalSalary) {
  let totalPay = salary + additionalSalary;
  return totalPay;
}

function 401k() {
  const totalPay = cal(salary, additionalSalary);
  const specialAccount = totalPay * 0.37;
  const normalAccount = totalPay - specialAccount;
}
```

**OR**

You can create a separate module where your `cal()` function is written and you export the `globalValriable` from that `example.js` file like this :

```
module.exports.cal = function (totalPay) { 
  console.log(totalPay);
};
```

**AND**

get it in the main file where needed :

```
var totalPay = require('respectiveDir'/thatModule);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [immediately invoked function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) expressions to handle `let totalPay` variable within your salary calculation:

Code:

```js
const Salary = (() => {
  let totalPay
  const cal = (salary, additionalSalary) => {
    totalPay = salary + additionalSalary
  }
  const k401 = () => {
    const specialAccount = totalPay * 0.37
    const normalAccount = totalPay - specialAccount
    return normalAccount
  }
  return {
    cal: cal,
    k401: k401
  }
})()

// Use it like this
Salary.cal(5000, 250)
const k401 = Salary.k401()

console.log('k401:', k401)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, so choose the better for your specific case.

1- **Deleting the keyword "var" in cal function:**

Doing that, the *totalPay* variable will have global scope. So, you will be able to manipulate it in another functions.

```
function cal(salary, additionalSalary) {
    var salary;
    var additionalSalary;
    totalPay = salary + additionalSalary;
}

function 401k() {
    var specialAccount = totalPay * 0.37;
    var normalAccount = totalPay - specialAccount;
}
```

Take in count that for use *totalPay* in function *401k*, you need first to call *cal* function

2- **Implement hoisting**

Just declare your variable in the beginning of the scope without make an assignation. Doing that, you're declaring a global var with global scope, so it can be called in functions scopes

```
var totalPay;
```

Then, you can specify your functions as belong

```
function cal(salary, additionalSalary) {
    var salary;
    var additionalSalary;
    totalPay = salary + additionalSalary;
}

function 401k() {
    var specialAccount = totalPay * 0.37;
    var normalAccount = totalPay - specialAccount;
}
```

Take in count, that the totalPay var is not declared in cal function, just asigned a value and for use *totalPay* in function *401k*, you need first to call *cal* function because if not it will be undefined.

3- **Keep vars localy**

Is a good practice to keep the managment of the vars localy, because with globals is easy to fail in the managment of values, lose the trazability of the changes and so on.

Any case, to implement this option you just need to return the *totalPay* var in *cal* function and after that, call *cal* function into *401k* function:

```
function cal(salary, additionalSalary) {
    var totalPay = salary + additionalSalary;
    return totalPay;
}

function 401k() {
    var totalPay = cal (salary, additionalSalary) ;
    var specialAccount = totalPay * 0.37;
    var normalAccount = totalPay - specialAccount;
}
```

My recommendation is to use **the option 3**, but the better solution is the one who adjust for your specific situation, so evaluate it and choose one.